# CSS changes will not show up instantly in browser - Codeigniter

Tags: php, css, codeigniter

**I have a problem about CSS in my codeigniter project.**

I have separate views for header, footer and for rest of the pages. I have loaded my CSS files inside the header view. every thing is working great. Only problem is that when I make a change inside my CSS file it wont show up even after refreshing the page. It will only show up if I restart the whole PC. I know this is not a very big problem, but it is making it harder to debug the project. I just want you guys to tell me what is it that i am missing or doing wrong.

**Thank you in advance.**

*P.S. i am student, new to codeigniter and also new to STACK OVERFLOW, so please think twice before down voting my question*

```
This is my HEADER.

<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="description" content="Colorlib Templates">
  <meta name="author" content="Colorlib">
  <meta name="keywords" content="Colorlib Templates">
  <title>User Authorization </title>
  <link href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/vendor/mdi-font/css/material-design-iconic-font.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
    <link href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/vendor/font-awesome-4.7/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
    <!-- Font special for pages-->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:100,100i,200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i,900,900i" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Vendor CSS-->
    <link href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/vendor/select2/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
    <link href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/vendor/datepicker/daterangepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">

    <!-- Main CSS-->
    <link href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
```

Comment: Did you try to clear the catche?

Comment: Thanks for your time. It worked! but do i always have to do it to see a change?

Comment: Take a look at my answer. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be a caching-problem. Please try to clear your cache, or disable caching.

> In Firefox and Chrome you should be able to reload the page with cleared cache by
>   pressing **ctrl + F5**. *(This could work in other browsers, too. But havn't tested)*

To get rid of the caching-problem you could try to set the following meta-tags in your head:

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
```

> to learn more take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/how-to-control-web-page-caching-across-all-browsers/2068407#2068407)